# Texture baking, some faces don't get lit properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking

I'm working on a camp site illustration and while baking the textures I've ran into a interesting problem I'm unable to solve. Regular cycles render:
[image]

Following a tutorial to bake textures I used "smart UV project" to unwrap the object in the center and baked the texture onto it with this result:
[image]

Some of the spheroids in the object get something like a inverted shadow - the areas that should be lit aren't, and the areas that should be dark are lit.

This only happens with the bush like illustration of a forest - all other elements in the scene appear to bake correctly.

Any ides what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: May be inverted normals?

Comment: Sounds like the most reasonable thing to me too, but the results are same when I do it - I select the dark objects and "Flip Direction" under "Normals:" in "Shading/UVs" on the left, that's what you mean right?

Comment: Yes I meant that. Other possibility, the margin in the bake panel. Or if else, could you upload your file?

Comment: Here's the file - http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2772/  (Edit: Just realized now that the file doesn't contain the baked texture and will require to rebake - sorry) I haven't learned yet how to change the margin in the bake panel - will look into that.

Comment: This is a normal problem. But when you flip direction, you need to select only the involved faces/bushes

Comment: Yes, that's what I did - selected only the involved ones rebaked but it baked the same result. Here's the fixed download of the file. http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2773/

Comment: To see that clearly, use the N panel (the one on the right of the 3D View), then look at 'mesh display' section, and make the faces normals appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53843/discussion-between-lemon-and-matthew-abrman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of the [discussion between Matthew Abrman and lemon](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53843/discussion-between-lemon-and-matthew-abrman).

1. Go into edit mode. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>
2. In the 3D Viewport Properties Panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) locate the **Mesh Display** section. Activate **Show Face Normals**.

Several Normals don't point in the right direction.

[image]

Selecting all and doing the Flip Normals operation would result in the correctly oriented normals to invert themselves.

3. Use the **Recalculate Normals** operation. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>